Github Bot(yaml) not making comments when PR is made
this is the code i've put but its not making a comment when someone requests a pr , help will be appreciated
name: Greetings

on: 
  pull_request_target:

jobs:
  greeting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Greet PR Submitter
        uses: actions/first-interaction@v1
        with:
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          pr-message: |
            Hello @${{ github.actor }}, thank you for submitting a PR! To allow your work to be integrated as seamlessly as possible, we advise you to:
            - Verify your PR is **up-to-date with origin/master.** 
            - Verify all Continuous Integration (CI) **checks are passing**.
            - Reduce changes to the absolute **minimum** required for your bug fix or feature addition. _"It is not daily increase but daily decrease, hack away the unessential." - Bruce Lee._

the workflow is triggered and succesful but no comments are being made , have checked permissions too

How did you check the token permission? Have you use it against the REST API to confirm that it can write comments?

What do the logs say?

name: Greetings

on:
  pull_request:

jobs:
  greeting:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Greet PR Submitter
        uses: actions/first-interaction@v1
        with:
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          pr-message: |
            Hello @${{ github.actor }}, thank you for submitting a PR! 
            To allow your work to be integrated as seamlessly as possible, we advise you to:
            - Verify your PR is up-to-date with origin/master.
            - Verify all Continuous Integration (CI) checks are passing.
            - Reduce changes to the absolute minimum required for your bug fix or feature addition.

            "It is not daily increase but daily decrease, hack away the unessential." - Bruce Lee.

Try pull_request and make sure Read and write permissions are selected under Workflow permissions. Hope that works
